# #include <Dbghelp.h> doesn't include the header

Tags: c++

If you include `#include <Dbghelp.h>` in, for example, a console C++ application, it will not bring any definitions from the header file and there are more or less similar compiler errors as if this header is not included at all.

Compiler errors looks like:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleDump, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  ConsoleDump.cpp
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(23): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Flags'
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(23): error C2065: 'Flags': undeclared identifier
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(23): error C2065: 'MiniDumpWithFullMemory': undeclared identifier
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(24): error C2065: 'MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo': undeclared identifier
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(25): error C2065: 'MiniDumpWithHandleData': undeclared identifier
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(26): error C2065: 'MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules': undeclared identifier
1>e:\projects\vs2015 projects\consoledump\consoledump\consoledump.cpp(27): error C2065: 'MiniDumpWithThreadInfo': undeclared identifier
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must included `<windows.h>` before `<DbgHelp.h>`, and if the project uses `"Stdafx.h"`, it must be included before everything else. The following is the correct order:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <Dbghelp.h>
```

Also make sure to link DbgHelp.lib to 'Project settings' > Linker > Input > 'Additional Dependencies'.

Comment: My sweet Jezus, I ran a clang-format and this was swapping both includes which put them alphabetically... If `Dbghelp.h` depends on `windows.h`, it should include it within...

Comment: I also encountered the same problem, windows is really not suitable for programming